# Configuring PLL in lpc2468

Tags: arm

I am working on a project on `lpc2468` and I need to configure the **PLL** i.e Phase locked loop in it.I am using a **main oscillator of 12MHz** and Want a **PLL output of 60MHz**. I am not able to calculate the accurate values of **pre-multiplier and pre-divider**. plz help how can i calculate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fics.nxp.com%2Fsupport%2Fdocuments%2Fmicrocontrollers%2Fxls%2Flpc23xx.lpc24xx.pll.calculator.xls&ei=q6oNT_P4McehtwexiOylBQ&usg=AFQjCNFRKI9qm2X6baibOTt2_XDgq2vnPQ&sig2=Q2uWcJnMIWJv5IkyHlYV0g

This spread sheet from NXP's website will help you configure your prescalers.